# Installing kivy on Anaconda, Python 2.7

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, kivy, anaconda

I am trying to install kivy on Python 2.7 (Anaconda, Mac OS X 10.5) but got the error when I run this:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label

class Hellokivy(App):

    def build (self):
        return Label(text="Hello kivy")

hellokivy=Hellokivy()

hellokivy.run()
```

the error is:

```
[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
 Exception SystemExit: 1 in 'kivy.properties.dpi2px' ignored
[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
```

SystemExit: 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the error is because pygame is not installed. To install it:
open up the terminal and type in:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew install sdl sdl_ttf sdl_image sdl_mixer portmidi
```

then:

```
conda install binstar
```

and then:

```
conda install anaconda-client
```

and finally;

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/quasiben pygame
```